# Setting up Traefik with Keycloak returns 500

Tags: ssl, openid, keycloak, traefik

I've been at this for several weeks and I can't figure out what is happening. Basically, I have an app that works when using nginx (ssl) and/or keycloak on port 8080 without ssl. But, I can't get it to work with using traefik for some reason.

I've looked everywhere and I'm not able to figure out why when I'm redirected from my app to keycloak I get a 500 internal error. I'm unable to get to keycloaks login page. I get a blank page. There appears to be an error in keycloak

ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-12) Failed to create error page: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.keycloak.theme.ExtendingThemeManager.loadTheme(ExtendingThemeManager.java:117)
    at org.keycloak.theme.ExtendingThemeManager.getTheme(ExtendingThemeManager.java:95)

https://keycloak.dev/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=formward&state=7a50ff93-46ad-419b-8428-fc662b17aa0e&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftravelvoucher.dev%2Fpdf%3Fauth_callback%3D1&scope=openid&response_type=code

returns 500

```
 https://keycloak.dev/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=formward&state=7a50ff93-46ad-419b-8428-fc662b17aa0e&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftravelvoucher.dev%2Fpdf%3Fauth_callback%3D1&scope=openid&response_type=code
```

returns 500

Here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
  keycloak:
    image: 'jboss/keycloak'
    container_name: keycloak
    #env_file: ./assets/keycloak.env
    #restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
     - keycloak_postgres
    volumes:
        #- keycloak_data:/var/lib/postgresql/keycloak
        #- ./assets/standalone.xml:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
      - ./cert.key:/etc/x509/https/cert.key
      - ./cert.crt:/etc/x509/https/cert.crt
    environment:
        - DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
        - DB_ADDR=keycloak_postgres
        - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
        - DB_USER=keycloak
        - DB_SCHEMA=public
        - DB_PASSWORD=password
        - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
        - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password
        - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
        - KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=ERROR # DEBUG, ERROR, INFO
    ports:
      - "8443"
    expose: 
      - "8080"
    labels:
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:keycloak.10.34.60.5.xip.io,keycloak.dev,keycloak.docker.localhost"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.X-Forwarded-For=10.34.60.5"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.X-Forwarded-Proto=https"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.X-Forwarded-Port=443"
    networks:
      - web
      - internal
      # This command is only required if using Traefik. It's not required if using nginx.
    command: ["-b", "0.0.0.0", "-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.docker=enabled"]

  keycloak_postgres:
    image: postgres
    #env_file: ./assets/keycloak.env
    #restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - keycloak_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      internal:
    expose:
     - "5432"
    labels:
     - "traefik.enable=false"

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    container_name: traefik
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "443:443"
      #- "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    expose:
      - "8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker event
      - ./assets/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - ./cert.key:/cert.key
      - ./cert.crt:/cert.crt
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:admin.10.34.60.5.xip.io,admin.dev"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
    networks:
      - web
```

Here is my traefik.toml configuration:

```
################################################################
# Global configuration
################################################################
InsecureSkipVerify = true
# Enable debug mode
#
# Optional
# Default: false
#
 debug = true

# Log level
#
# Optional
# Default: "ERROR"
#
 logLevel = "ERROR"

# Entrypoints to be used by frontends that do not specify any entrypoint.
# Each frontend can specify its own entrypoints.
#
# Optional
# Default: ["http"]
#
 defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

################################################################
# Entrypoints configuration
################################################################

# Entrypoints definition
#
# Optional
# Default:
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/cert.crt"
      keyFile = "/cert.key"

################################################################
# Traefik logs configuration
################################################################

# Traefik logs
# Enabled by default and log to stdout
#
# Optional
#
# [traefikLog]

# Sets the filepath for the traefik log. If not specified, stdout will be used.
# Intermediate directories are created if necessary.
#
# Optional
# Default: os.Stdout
#
# filePath = "log/traefik.log"

# Format is either "json" or "common".
#
# Optional
# Default: "common"
#
# format = "common"

################################################################
# Access logs configuration
################################################################

# Enable access logs
# By default it will write to stdout and produce logs in the textual
# Common Log Format (CLF), extended with additional fields.
#
# Optional
#
# [accessLog]

# Sets the file path for the access log. If not specified, stdout will be used.
# Intermediate directories are created if necessary.
#
# Optional
# Default: os.Stdout
#
# filePath = "/path/to/log/log.txt"

# Format is either "json" or "common".
#
# Optional
# Default: "common"
#
# format = "common"

################################################################
# API and dashboard configuration
################################################################

# Enable API and dashboard
[api]

  # Name of the related entry point
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: "traefik"
  #
  # entryPoint = "traefik"

  # Enabled Dashboard
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: true
  #
  # dashboard = false

################################################################
# Ping configuration
################################################################

# Enable ping
[ping]

  # Name of the related entry point
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: "traefik"
  #
  # entryPoint = "traefik"

################################################################
# Docker configuration backend
################################################################

# Enable Docker configuration backend
[docker]
network = "web"
watch = true
# Docker server endpoint. Can be a tcp or a unix socket endpoint.
#
# Required
# Default: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
#
# endpoint = "tcp://10.10.10.10:2375"

# Default domain used.
# Can be overridden by setting the "traefik.domain" label on a container.
#
# Optional
# Default: ""
#
domain = "dev"

# Expose containers by default in traefik
#
# Optional
# Default: true
#
# exposedByDefault = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing Keycloak's `master` realm with a specific configuration (`client_id` = `formward`) yet it's unclear how you built this config, it's not mentioned in `docker-compose.yml`. One of the possible realm configuration/build steps is extending or changing the default theme. The error message says that whatever theme is configured, Keycloak can't find it. You might have performed configuration manually on a running instance of Keycloak and/or imported a realm with this config from somewhere, either way this configuration state did not persist (not everything Keycloak does/uses is stored in the database)

Recommendation: take a step back and compose Keycloak without Traefik, make sure it's healthy, add the config steps to your docker-compose, then add Traefik.

Comment: Is there a way to reset the settings from keycloak? And you are right -- The custom theme was not carried over from the previous server. The data was imported using the import function, but not all of the data appears to be there.

Comment: @TheBetterJORT To reset the config on a running instance, you'd have to import a clean config (of an entire realm). Easiest way to grab that clean config is fire up a base Docker image with a fresh filesystem and the same version of Keycloak you're using and [export](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/server/README.md#exporting-a-realm)  the master realm. You can then [import](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/server/README.md#importing-a-realm) it into your instance. You might want to backup your current realm (via an export..) prior to this.

Comment: I really can't believe this comes down to not selecting a theme in the client settings. This feels like a bug, but I'm glad its resolved. Thank you.